# Better readability and simplicity versus higher complicity and speed in programming, what to chose?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, optimization, imperative-programming

Solving my homework for Informatics at University, I always find different ways to solve the same problem. 
One way is the fastest(execution time) but the longest and more complex. 
And the other is way easier to realize, falls short in execution time, it's easy to understand and so on.

As an mini-example is that we have have to create a program in C++, which outputs a line of N elements where each element has same adjacent elements different of that in the middle.

```
Ex.    
6 Elements: *_*_*_
7 Elements: *_*_*_*
```

**First solution is the easiest:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    for (int i=1; i<=a; i++)
    {
        if (i%2 != 0)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**And the second one is a little bit harder to implement but faster to execute(less conditionals checks):**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    if (a%2 == 1)
    {
        for (int i=1; i<=a; i=i+2)
        {
            cout << "*";
            cout << " ";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i=1; i<a; i=i+2)
        {
            cout << "*";
            cout << " ";
        }
        cout << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My question is what should I focus on? Clean code, easy to implement/deploy and better readability or best algorithm, faster to execute and strong logic, or just try as best as possible to mix all these 2, because there is always a discrepancy between these 2 ways of solving problems?

Comment: I'd go for solution 2 with only one cout for better speed :)  `for (int i=1; i<=a; i=i+2)  {   cout << "* "; }` BTW I believe there's a typo in example 2: both loops issue the star & space in the same order.

Comment: Nice notice ;), the space was as an example, let's say instead of space is "-"

Comment: I don't see any reason to have 2 loops for the second version,  why not just put the conditional at the end?

Comment: My advice: avoid copy/paste, and avoid tests in the inner loop. None of your both examples achieve this.

Comment: Optimization depends on the project.  In consumer products, the aim is to get the software completed A.S.A.P.; so getting a working version is top priority and speed is a lesser priority.  In Event Critical applications, where timing is important, speed can be very important.  There is no golden rule for everything.

Comment: One optimization trick is to *build* your text rows into strings, then output the strings.  This reduces the calls to `cout` from once for each character to one per row.  Calling functions has an overhead, and reducing the overhead can speed up your program.

Comment: There is no difference between the `for` loops, so get rid of one of them.  Less code means less possible defects and less time to test your code.

Comment: This question has been asked several times at least. It is a false dichotomy to think you have to trade off clarity for performance. Also, performance is never where you think it is, so you have to find it in the running of the program, not in the writing. [*Here is a good way to do it.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *should* try to write readable, easy to debug code for an ease of understanding.

Whenever you encounter portions of code where it can be heavily optimized in order to get much higher performance (either by modifying the code's architecture or/and by implementing assembly in your code), you can add in a commented section the better performance alternative of it. Even if you choose the better performance alternative, you'll always have the other one which can back up you up, in order to understand it.

Also, stick to better performance alternatives when you can see huge gains by doing it so, not every time.

Keep in mind that these improvements are better to be **only implemented** in the case of **performance bottlenecks** or in systems where **power efficiency** is crucial.

Comment: Just make that _If and when you encounter performance problems_.

Comment: I did make an edit based on what you've suggested. Thank you :)